# php access class by string

Tags: php, class, syntax-error

The following code works fine on my localhost and my first hoster, but not at my new hoster.

```
static function setup ($childModel) {
  query::create()
   ->name($childModel::$tableName)
   ->mayExist()
   ->row($childModel::$struct)
   ->key($childModel::$index)
   ->run();
}
```

`$childModel` contains a string with the name of a class. Worked fine so far, but the new server says:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM in /***/model.php on line 71
```

(line 71 is line 3 of the code above)

I know this means that he dont like the `::`, but why do none of my other servers complain here? And what can I do about this?

UPDATE: It works now. It seems like it just took time for the server to switch to the new php version. Sorry everybody! (How do I close this thread?)

Comment: What versions of PHP are your 3 servers running?  My guess is the new one is using an older one.

Comment: All servers run with php 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$childModel::$tableName` syntax (using variables as class names) only works in PHP 5.3+.

It seems like your new host is using an older version of PHP.